# Oracle SQL and PL/SQL 'make' tool

Tags: sql, oracle, svn, plsql

Oracle 11gR2
Linux RHEL 6.3
Subversion 1.7

Trying to find a build tool like 'make', 'ant', 'maven' for Oracle PL/SQL or SQL that will allow me to build my Oracle PL/SQL and SQL application.  Seems I can't find tool that will, for example, maintain the precedence needed to run my SQL (e.g. DDL) in the correct order.  I can compare differences between two schemas and generate DDL that will sync the two schemas.  But the order that this DDL is generated in does not take into account precedence -- e.g. parent table build should occur before child table but instead the DDL output is in alphabetical order.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any particular reason this is tagged `svn`? I don't see where Subversion fits into this.

Comment: I am using SVN and was wondering if there were any helpful svn commands that may add to the building of such a tool.  Turns out the 'diff' command helps somewhat in the building of my tool to (at least) let me know what files have changed from release to release (last tag to trunk e.g.)

Answer (score 1):

I use make and a make file like this. But I have the db password in the file! Also all ddl creation files are separate in the same folder. You need at least the oracle instant client with sqlplus installed.

```
    # When on Windows and starting GNU make from Git bash, we need to set this:
    ifdef COMSPEC
       SHELL=C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe
    endif

    export ORASYSDBA="sys/oracle@192.168.0.112:1521/orcl as sysdba"

    uninstall:
        sqlplus ${ORASYSDBA} @uninstall.sql

    install: tablespaces users directories  sequences package_reapi_headers tables types  views sysgrants package_headers package_bodies 

        sqlplus ${ORASYSDBA} @create_directories.sql

    tablespaces:
        sqlplus ${ORASYSDBA} @create_tablespaces.sql

    users:
        sqlplus ${ORASYSDBA} @create_users.sql
```

You then simply call it by

```
make install
```

or

```
make users
```